# Let $p:X \rightarrow Y$ be a perfect map. Show that if $X$ is locally compact then so is $Y$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $p:X \rightarrow Y$ be a perfect map, that is, $p$ is closed, continuous, surjective, and $p^{-1}(y)$ is compact for every $y \in Y$. Show that if $X$ is locally compact, then so is $Y$.

There are a couple of these perfect map problems on one of our old qualifying exams. They seem really difficult. I've been working on this one all night and can't figure it out.

Comment: Already answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453004/show-that-y-is-locally-compact?rq=1